# PHP User Agent based session authentication

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, authentication, user-agent

I have a User-Agent based session authentication. After every request, I check if the user agent has changed. If so, the user is logged out (Session may have been hijacked).

It all worked out perfectly until... some IE users complained about problems after ajax requests.

After some sleepless nights I started to log the user agents for every request and compared them. And WTF, some IE versions append " ICAPoHTTPS" to the user agent if it's an ajax request.

Does anybody have an idea why?

Thanks and I hope it will help others...

Answer (score 0):

Useful news, havn't noticed that.

Anyway, I would not use User Agent as it's software/header based and if someone is able to hijack session and incject cookies to browser properly, he is probably able to hijack user agent string and inject it too.

I'am usually using REMOTE_ADDR, what also is not preventing from person working from same subnetwork as its victim.

---

**Edit:**

You may walk-around this by sending your sign-in form via ajax, and than redirect on success. Assuming session is fresh on form display, it will collect standard user agent string, and on sign-in action a secondary one. This way, in your situation, you will collect at most two User Agent strings you want to check.

Hopefully you are aware of fact, that User Agent is editable header and may be used to [inject malicious code/queries](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-shellshock/).

Comment: I thought about using the ip address, but on mobile devices there are often dynamic IPs (i.e. my ip change on every request). Also on "normal" internet conections there are dynamic ips, and this could cause problems if you have a long lasting session.

Comment: You may want to take use of [CSRF tokenizing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) pattern than. It has its drawbacks, but it's quite a resistant solution. Depends on kind of service you are working on.

Comment: I fixed it by removing "ICAPoHTTPS" from the user agent. I know thats not a clean way but for the moment that should do the job.

But in the future I will certainly do it with the ajax login and save both user agents. 

Yes I am aware, but as I am using only a hash of the user agent, that shouldn't be a security issue. Thanks!